# Unable to Publish Jsonbuffer[768] to mqtt using Pubsub client.(Controller esp32 Wroom 32)

Tags: arrays, mqtt

Unable to publish (Thermal sensor of 32X24)  data to Mqtt Using PUBSUBCLIENT.h,

Since data of Sensor is in (float) array format mlx90640To[x]".

WHEN TRY TO PUBLISH DATA TO TOPIC "ev8051/esp32/temperature" I ONLY RECEIVED 128 BYTE ON MQTT BOX. IMAGE OF MQTT BOX SHARE BELOW.

CODE:-

```
 DynamicJsonDocument doc(13000);  
 doc["device"] = "ESP32";
doc["sensorType"] = "T-Scanner";
  char arr[786];
  for (int x = 0 ; x < 768 ; x++)   //768 384
  {  
  Serial.print(mlx90640To[x],0);  //value from sensor print on com port
    doc["values"][x] = (uint8_t)mlx90640To[x];   // AARAY value of 786 is store in values
    Serial.print(",");
  }
  Serial.println("\nSending message to MQTT topic..");
 **  char JSONmessageBuffer[cap];                            // JSON MESSAGE CHAR BUFFER **
   Serial.println(serializeJson(doc, Serial));
   size_t n = serializeJson(doc, JSONmessageBuffer);     // formation of serialization of data


   ** //*************************Data send to PUBLISH TO MQTT TOPIC******************************/**
if (client.publish("ev8051/esp32/temperature",JSONmessageBuffer) == true) // sending JSONmessageBuffer data to topic "ev8051/esp32/temperature"
{  
    Serial.println("\nSuccess sending message");
  } else {
    Serial.println("\nError sending message");
  }
```

Please help me out, I won't read a total array of 768 on the MQTT box using the topic "ev8051/esp32/temperature"

[image: COM AND MQTT BOX IMAGE]

Comment: Not sure I understand this. You say your image is 32x24 pixels, so presumably that means you have 768 pixels? Or 768 temperature values. If you encode that as JSON (which is text), then if a pixel is at a temperature of 33 degrees, you will have to actually send "33," which is 3 bytes, so I would expect your MQTT payload to be at least 768*3 bytes plus all the JSON overhead, so 2400+ bytes. But it is 793 bytes....

Comment: Any progress with this?